# Reverse Osmosis Tank Not Filling after working for 2 months

Tags: water

I've had RO systems for years. I replace filters annually and have never had any problems with flow rate. We are connected to city water and have plenty of pressure on the supply side. My last system gradually started to produce less and less water from the RO faucet. Initially I thought the pressure tank was failing and added some air. But that didn't help. I changed filters, RO membrane, the ASO valve, and restrictor valve, and pressure tank with no improvement. I gave up and bought a new system and it worked great for about 2 months.

So.. I have a 2 month old system that has been working great, but all of a sudden the pressure at the faucet has dropped to almost nothing and the tank won't fill.
Supplies are on. Filters are 2 months old, pressure tank is at 7 psi, and the drain line is free and clear.
I'm at a loss. Since it is the same problem as before what am I missing?

Thanks
Jason

Comment: A little late to the party, but it sounds like this would be time for a service call to the installer. You'd think they'd have a warranty that lasts more than 2 months.

Comment: disconnect one line at the time (into a bucket) and observe the flow

Answer (score 1):

Is there any chance that you have a saddle valve which taps your cold water line? It is typical for that type of valve to clog over time if you have hard water …

Comment: I do, but I detached the line before it goes into the RO filters and it definitely has good pressure and flow.

Answer (score 1):

So you replaced almost all the parts, but a new system did resolve the problem last time.  I would have suspected the ASO valve first.

If you want to fix this yourself, consider investing in a pressure gauge.  These are about $20.  Hook it up to the various lines to collect data.  Or, as one of the comments suggested, simply turn on the system with each different line disconnected to verify reasonable pressure coming out.

You've already narrowed the problem to somewhere between the supply and the tank.  Keep troubleshooting and you can figure it out.